# Export\Import SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, import, export

Is there a way to export\import SharePoint 2010 site, respecting the points below:

1. Import with same Ids (same content types and fields ids)
2. Import only the structure of the site, import document libraries, library templates etc.. without the content
3. Import User and Groups and related securities

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing. You mention export and import, but then list only import. What do you mean by "same Ids"? I don't know what that means or what it refers to. What do you even mean by importing and exporting?

Comment: sames Ids means that if i have content type named ct1 having 0x01989 so after we import the site i want the ct1 in the same Id 0x01989 same for fields. I didn't mention anything about export because i think the work is in the import process.

Comment: I mean by import and export that i want to export structure from site A and Import it on Site B, so site B will be a copy of site A but without content

Comment: Might look into using templates. That copies content unfortunately, but has all the other functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. Just to name a few:

- Save the site as a template
- Use Copy-SPSite, or use the Export-SPWeb, Backup-SPSite, Import-SPWeb, and Restore-SPSite commands
- Use the ExportWeb and ImportWeb feature of the Sites.asmx web service
- Create a custom site definition for your site
- Use PnP Provisioning Templates
- Use 3rd-party software

If you want to not include content, I'd recommend saving the site as a template (you can now save the template without content) or PnP provisioning.